# $rootScope is not defined in controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Below is my definition of controller. When I run the application, i get

"$rootScope is not defined".

Can anyone help me to understand what's wrong here.

```
var webadmin = angular.module('PcPortal')
    .controller('environmentController',
    [
        '$scope', '$http', '$rootScope',
        function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('http://localhost:52240/api/PcpEnvironment/GetAllEnvironments')
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.Environments = response.data;
                });

            $scope.findSelectedItem = function (index) {
                var env = $scope.Environments[index];
                $rootScope.selectedEnv = env;
            };

        }
    ]);
```

Html line to call function...

```
 <td><a  ng-click="findSelectedItem($index)" href="#/UpdateEnvironment">Update</a></td>
```

Comment: Error is clear. `function ($scope, $http, $rootScope)`

Comment: You're missing the `$rootScope` parameter in your controller function...

Comment: Just add $rootScope to function ($scope, $http , $rootScope).............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are injecting `$rootScope` but creating its instance as `$http`

Try this and create `$http` instance as `$http` and `$rootScope` instance as `$rootScope`

```
var webadmin = angular.module('PcPortal')
    .controller('environmentController',
    [
        '$scope', '$http', '$rootScope',
        function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
            $http.get('http://localhost:52240/api/PcpEnvironment/GetAllEnvironments')
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.Environments = response.data;
                });

            $scope.findSelectedItem = function (index) {
                var env = $scope.Environments[index];
                $rootScope.selectedEnv = env;
            };

        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Got it... it worked perfectly as I want... Thanks a lot
Can you explain why I need '$http' two times....

Comment: @Abhash786: you shouldn't use `'$http', '$http'`. that's silly. This answer is incorrect, as your `$rootScope` will not work properly.

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah that was really silly, that was typo now check, :)

Comment: if I remove one '$http' ... code doesn't work as expected